# WCF clients, hold reference or not?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Consider the following scenario:

There is a windows service hosting a WCF service.

The WCF service provides an interface between clients and an AppFabric server located on a physically different machine. It retreievs objects, does calculations on it and returns the best one.

20-30 clients can connect to the service at the same time which is not that much.

What would be better, create an instance every time a query is done on the service or have the client object as a member and call functions. Creating an instance litters everything with try finally block which I dont like but what about the client connection, what are the disadvantages? Can the host be restarted and have clients still work? What is the usual/preferred way to do this?

```
try
{
  PreOrderService.PreorderServiceClient proxy = new   PreOrderService.PreorderServiceClient("netTcpPreorderService");

  List<PreOrder> preOrders = proxy.FindWallet(preOrder.WalletId);
}
finally
{
  if (proxy.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
    proxy.Close();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practice for WCF proxy lifetime - or how often to close a WCF proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047524/best-practice-for-wcf-proxy-lifetime-or-how-often-to-close-a-wcf-proxy)

Comment: I had an answer which I deleted, because further reading (ie the possible duplicate question from CodeCaster, and some of the points CodeCaster brought up in comments on my answer) showed me that my own answer was clueless.  The one important part I want to get across - even if you do make your proxy an object member (pretty sure you still can), you'll still need try/catch/finally around each call through the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do the following:

```
proxy = newServiceReference1.ServiceDataContractTestClient(); 
try
{ 
    proxy.MetodThrowsException();
    proxy.Close(); 
} 
catch
{ 
    proxy.Abort(); 
    throw; // Or handle exception
}
```

This does not care if the server connection has been lost, and does not throw a CommunicationObjectFaultedException when proxy.MetodThrowsException() breaks the server.

If you find that it reduces readability, then wrap it in a separate method.